# How can I specify that fzf --preview should only find files within the current directory?

Tags: fzf

`fzf --preview 'cat {}'` gives me a two-pane terminal window of (left) a [fzf fuzzy search](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) for files and (right) a preview of said files.

When called, it starts out showing me `/Users/tomnorway/Downloads`, regardless of my current directory. I'd like to write a command that only finds files/folders within my current directory (recursively). Having read through `man fzf` to the best of my ability, I find no way to specify that. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: That's strange - I believe the default behaviour of fzf is indeed to search the
current directory... what do you get if you do `echo $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS` and
`echo $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND`?

Comment: Interesting! Well, I get nothing returned for the first one, and `fd . /Users/tomnorway` for the second. Any thoughts? I am definitely by default getting a list of directories outside of my current directory (I navigated a few steps into a git repo before calling `fzf --preview 'cat {}'`). I can then type the git repo name and it does find that.

Comment: Actually I think this is the intended default: `export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='fd --type f'` see https://github.com/junegunn/fzf (see under the 'Environmental variables' heading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you response in the comments, given that the output of `echo $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` is:

```
fd . /Users/tomnorway
```

You should go into your ~/.bashrc and replace the line:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='fd . /Users/tomnorway'
```

with:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='fd --type f'
```

#### Bonus

I also have an answer for if you want fzf to search a dedicated shortlist of
directories (e.g. Docs, Downloads, Pics, Vids, Admin, MyDir... etc.) regardless
of where you are in the filesystem
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/67019648/14467607). I like this because it
effectively means I can find any file at any time (but without cluttering the
fzf list with thousands of random files from various installations in my home
directory).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! :)