# Make fzf `**<TAB>` completion only return files for specific command (caveat inside!)

Tags: shell, zsh, fzf

I'm trying to make `fzf`s autocompletion invoked on `cat **<TAB>` return only files (directories does not make sense for `cat`). According to [docs](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#custom-fuzzy-completion) it's the matter of defining `_fzf_complete_cat()`, so my first try was

```
_fzf_complete_cat() {
  _fzf_complete -- "$@" < <(
    fd --type f --hidden --follow --no-ignore --exclude .git 
  )
}
```

however, there's a major flaw: this completion does not take into account the path's part before `**`, e.g. if I am in `~/subdir` and type `cat ~/another/**<TAB>` it will not recurse from there, but rather from `~/subdir`.

I understand the trick is around these lines from [fzf/shell/completion.zsh](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/completion.zsh#L302), namely, the way `_fzf_[path|dir]_completion()` handles it. So I tried smth like that (essentially, repeating the logic of the `completion.zsh`):

```
_custom_fzf_compgen_path() {
  fd --hidden --follow --no-ignore --exclude ".git" . "$1"
}

_custom_fzf_path_completion() {
  __fzf_generic_path_completion "$1" "$2" _fzf_compgen_path \
    "-m" "" " "
}

_fzf_complete_cat() {
  _custom_fzf_path_completion "$prefix" "$1"
}
```

and it almost works, messing up in the very end with `zle reset-prompt` from [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/completion.zsh#L304).

TL;DR: I need `**<TAB>` for `cat` command work similarly to `_fzf_[path|dir]_completion()` but return only files.

Appreciate any ideas! Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64416946/14467607) of mine might help you (particularly if combined with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67019648/14467607)).

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to do that in a way alighned with the how fzf invokes tab completion for relative paths (it extracts base) so I ended up tweaking fzf's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going down the initial path of tweaking `_fzf_complete_cat()`. It uses a wonderful function `__fzf_generic_path_completion()` which takes care of splitting the path yped before `**<TAB>` (e.g. `cat ~/some_other_dir/**<TAB>`) and finding the base of it. Problem lied around extra `zle reset-prompt` in [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/completion.zsh#L304), so I had to create my own `__fzf_generic_path_completion()` without it.

Full working solution

```
__custom_fzf_generic_path_completion() {
  local base lbuf cmd compgen fzf_opts suffix tail dir leftover matches
  base=$1
  lbuf=$2
  cmd=$(__fzf_extract_command "$lbuf")
  compgen=$3
  fzf_opts=$4
  suffix=$5
  tail=$6

  setopt localoptions nonomatch
  eval "base=$base"
  [[ $base = *"/"* ]] && dir="$base"
  while [ 1 ]; do
    if [[ -z "$dir" || -d ${dir} ]]; then
      leftover=${base/#"$dir"}
      leftover=${leftover/#\/}
      [ -z "$dir" ] && dir='.'
      [ "$dir" != "/" ] && dir="${dir/%\//}"
      matches=$(eval "$compgen $(printf %q "$dir")" | FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="--height ${FZF_TMUX_HEIGHT:-40%} --reverse --bind=ctrl-z:ignore $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS $FZF_COMPLETION_OPTS" __fzf_comprun "$cmd" ${(Q)${(Z+n+)fzf_opts}} -q "$leftover" | while read item; do
        echo -n "${(q)item}$suffix "
      done)
      matches=${matches% }
      if [ -n "$matches" ]; then
        LBUFFER="$lbuf$matches$tail"
      fi
      # REMOVED HERE zle reset-prompt
      break
    fi
    dir=$(dirname "$dir")
    dir=${dir%/}/
  done
}

_custom_fzf_compgen_path() {
  # Add here your favorite command to search for files. $1 is the starting
  # point.
  fd --type f --hidden --follow --no-ignore --exclude ".git" . "$1"
}

_custom_fzf_path_completion() {
  __custom_fzf_generic_path_completion "$1" "$2" _custom_fzf_compgen_path \
    "-m" "" " "
}

_fzf_complete_cat() {
  # $prefix is the variable set by fzf here https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/completion.zsh#L302
  _custom_fzf_path_completion "$prefix" "$1"
}
```